# Кто такая "ружа"?

Tags: этимология

Помните анекдот: "Штирлиц вышел наружу. Через несколько дней польского агента Ружу расстреляли"?
А вот, действительно, что такое эта "ружа", на которую выходят? Понятно, что сейчас "наружу" - это цельное наречие, к которому "на" прочно припаялось, но изначально-то была какая-то "ружа".))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**наружу**

Искон. Сращение предл.-пад. формы *на ружу,* где *ружу* — вин. п. ед. ч. от *ружа* «внешность, вид», в диалектах еще известного.

*Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.*

http://etymological.academic.ru/3014